# How can I see the Entity Framework's pending changes?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm creating an application with the ADO.NET Entity Framework.

I can step through my code line-by-line while debugging and watch SQL Server Profiler for every query executed, but I can't figure out where all those SQL commands are coming from!

Sometimes when I execute `SaveChanges()`, the Entity Framework performs unexpected, weird INSERTS.  They sometimes break the application.  I can't figure out what I'm doing to cause them.

How can I monitor the pending changes that queue up waiting for a `SaveChanges()` call?

Answer (score 72):

Since Entity Framework 5.0 `DbContext` has a [`ChangeTracker` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Gg696736(v=vs.103).aspx) which has all pending changes. Similar to the `ObjectStateManager` you can get entities in various states as follows:

```
myDbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added);
myDbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Deleted);
myDbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Modified);
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like this is the only correct answer for EF5+

Comment: I can't seem to access that in the Immediate Windows! I get [this error](http://imgur.com/a/2CsQn).

Comment: Okay, is there a way to get the SQL that EF is going to attempt for those changes?

Comment: Append .ToList() to the end to cause the Linq to be executed so you can view the data from the watch window.

Comment: EF advise against enumerating the `Entries`. Creating a `new List<EntityEntry>()` and calling `AddRange(myDbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries())` on it works fine, you can then use it in VS Immediate Window

Answer (score 23):

Take a look at

```
myObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
```

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738497.aspx).

Comment: If you're using a DbContext object then you'll need to cast it to an IObjectContextAdapter before you can access the ObjectStateManager.  Example:((IObjectContextAdapter)dbcontext).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager

Answer (score 8):

To monitor the events when entities are added to or removed from the state manager, you can use [ObjectStateManagerChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager.objectstatemanagerchanged.aspx) event:

```
var ctx = new ModelContainer();

// ...

ctx.ObjectStateManager.ObjectStateManagerChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
   Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}", e.Action, e.Element));
};
```

Answer (score 6):

**Entity Framework 6** has a method for that, really useful.

```
dbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges()
```

Example:

```
if (dbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges())
{
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I attempted to view the `ObjectStateManager` mentioned in the other answers it didn't show up in my debugger. When debugging in Visual Studio 2017, I've found it helpful to add the following snippet to a watch (which casts the dbContext object before referencing the ObjectStateManager property).

`((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)this.db).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager`

Once the watch is made, you can debug line by line watching what actions add to the various properties that list pending changes.

Answer (score 0):

From docs: [Change Tracker Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/debug-views):

You also can see all entities changes by  `ChangeTracker.DebugView`:

```
context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
Console.WriteLine(context.ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView);
```

[image]