# Prevent cached objects to end up in the database with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, caching

We have an ASP.NET project with Entity Framework and SQL Azure.

A big part of our data only needs to be updated a few times a day, other data is very volatile.

- The data that barely changes we cache in memory at startup, detach from the context and than use it mainly for reading, drastically lowering the amount of database requests we have to do.
- The volatile data is requested everytime by a DbContext per Http request.
- When we do an update to the cached data, we send a message to all instances to catch a fresh version of all the data from the SQL server.

So far, so good.

Until we introduced a bug that linked one of these 'cached' objects to the 'volatile' data, and did a SaveChanges.

Well, that was quite a mess.

The whole data tree was added **again** and **again** by every update, corrupting the whole database with a whole lot of duplicated data.

As a complete hack I added a completely arbitrary column with a UniqueConstraint and some gibberish data on one of the root tables; hopefully failing the SaveChanges() next time we introduce such a bug because it will violate the Unique Constraint.

But it is of course hacky, and I'm still pretty scared ;P 
Are there any better ways to prevent whole tree's of cached objects ending up in the database?

**More information**

- Project is ASP.NET MVC
- I cache this data, because it is mainly read only, and this saves a tons of extra database calls per http request
- This is in a high traffic website, with a lot of personal customized views. Having the POCO data in memory works really good for what I want. Except the problem I mentioned.
- It is a bit more complicated, but a simplified version is that I cache the objects by a singleton: so i.e:

`EntityCache.Instance.LolCats = new DbContext().LolCats.AsNoTracking().ToList();`

This cache I dependency-inject into my controllers.

Comment: Yes, set foreign key values in stead of objects.

Comment: Might not always be possible, because some of the business logic might depent on the Navigation property.

Comment: Where are you caching this data? And is your project ASP.NET WebForms or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Why is it necessary to detach from the context?

Comment: I'm caching this data because I need it almost every Http request, but is mainly static data (only changes once day). I am using ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @DirkBoer I asked **where** you're caching the data. Are you caching it in HttpRuntime.Cache, Redis or what?

Comment: It might not needed to detach from the context, but the fact remains that is coming from a different DbContext than the 'volatile' requests, see description.

Comment: Ah sorry @RaduPorumb. Misread your question. I'm caching the data in-memory, just as objects. This means that I don't need to deserialize the data, or do any external calls. So it's mega fast.

Comment: @DirkBoer Can you give me a code example of how exactly you're caching the data in memory? Since it's an ASP.NET MVC application there aren't a lot of places where you can cache something and have it persist across requests.

Comment: added into the explanation @RaduPorumb

Comment: @DirkBoer I'm guessing that the EntityCache object is a singleton you have defined in Global.asax?

Comment: @DirkBoer Is this EntityCache a custom solution you're using? I'm asking because the most popular caching solutions are key/value stores and you seem to have hardcoded object names.

Comment: Yeah @RaduPorumb it is just simply storing the POCO objects in a singleton. Even with key/value stores I'm wasting a lot just on deserialising all the data from text **per request**. The current solution works perfectly well for this kind of data, I'm just having troubles when they are being added to the database by accident. The custom 'UniqueConstraint' fixes this for now, but I'm looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

1) Create an interface like this:

```
public interface IIsReadOnly
{
    bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }
}
```

2) Implement this interface in all of the entities that can be cached. When you read and cache them, set the `IsReadOnly` property to `true`. This flag will be used when `SaveChanges` is invoked.  Remember to decorate this property with the `[NotMapped]` attribute, or use any other mean to make EF ignore it.

```
public class ACacheableEntitySample
   : IIsReadOnly
{
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsReadOnly { get; set; }

    // define the "regular" entity properties
}
```

*NOTE: you can include the property directly in the class definition (if using Code First), or use partial classes (for Db First, Model First, or Code First).*

*NOTE: alternatively you can make EF ignore the `IsReadOnly` property using the Fluent API, or even better [a custom convention (EF 6+)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx)*

3) Override your inherited `DbContext.SaveChanges` method. In the overridden method, [review all the entries with pending changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592504/how-can-i-see-the-entity-frameworks-pending-changes), and if they are read only, change there state to `Unchanged`:

```
if (entry is IIsReadOnly) // if it's a cacheable entity
{
    if (entry.IsReadOnly) // and it was marked as readonly when caching
    {
         // change the entry state to unchanged here, so that it's not updated
    }
}
```

*NOTE: This is sample code to explain what you need to do. In your final implementation you can do it with a simple LINQ sentence that get all the `IIsReadOnly` entities, which have the `IsReadOnly` set to true, and set their state to `Unchanged`.*

You can use the `IIsReadOnly` entites in another `DbContext` and manipulate them in the usual way. For example if you get one of these entites, update it, and call `SaveChanges`, the changes will be saved because `IsReadOnly` will have the default `false` value. But you'll easily avoid saving changes of cached data accidentally, simply by setting the `IsReadOnly` property to true when caching.

Comment: Wonderful solution! Did you worked this out just for my question, or are you using similar caching mechanisms in your applications?

Comment: It was just for your question. I've overloaded `SaveChanges` for other pruposes. Don't forget to make your singleton thread safe: i.e lock the reads until the cache is ready. You can use any of the available thread safe collections to avoid doing it yourself (and make some mistake!). You can find a lot of information on this collections, for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

*Original answer deleted because it was a waste of time.*

Your post and proceeding comments are a perfect example of [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You say:

> I really need a solution for the problem, not for the architecture

#### What if the architecture *is* the problem?

---

### The problem you presented

A caching solution you implemented that violates at least a half dozen best practices has (surprise!) blown up in your face. You've managed to stop it from blowing again up via a spectacular (not in a good way) hack but you want to know how to do it in a way that won't require such a spectacular hack.

### The problem you had

You needed to cache some data because it was getting too expensive to hit the database for every request.

---

### The answers that were offered

#### Use foreign keys instead of navigation properties

This is a perfectly valid answer and, surprise, a best practice. Navigation properties can change any time you regenerate the code in your Entity Data Model and are often ambiguous. With a bit of effort you could have used this and never had to worry about EF's handling of object relationships again.

#### Cache models instead of Entity objects

Another valid answer, and one that requires the least amount of actual work. MVC applications usually require some redundancy between viewmodels and entity objects and if you ever write a proper multi-tier application you'll practically drown in redundant objects. And nobody will accidentally add these objects to a DbContext ever again - because they can't.

### Criticism

You have offered up very little useful information. From what I can tell your approach from the get-go was wrong.

Firstly, dumping whole tables into memory at App_Start is at best a temporary solution. If the table was too big to hit on every request, it's too big to hit on App_Start. What happens if something important breaks while people are using your application and you need to deploy a bug fix ASAP? What happens when your tables get *really* big and you start getting timeouts from EF while trying to dump them into memory? What happens if 95% of your users only really ever need 10% of that big table you've dumped into memory? Is the memory on your web/cache server going to be enough to accommodate the increasing size of your tables? For how long?

Secondly, no Entity object should remain anywhere after its originating DbContext is disposed. Entity objects behave in a convenient way while their DbContext is in scope and become troublesome POCOs when it's out of scope. I say troublesome because the 'magic' DbContext does with change tracking tends to fool people unfamiliar with the inner workings of EF into thinking that an Entity object is directly connected to a table row in the database. The problem you had illustrates this point perfectly.

Thirdly, it looks like you need to delete and re-dump a whole table to memory, even if you only update a single column in a single row. That's immensely wasteful to both the memory and CPU on your web server, and to your Azure SQL instance(s). What happens when a small bit of data comes in wrong and needs to be updated in a hurry? What if one of your nightly update jobs fails but you need fresh data in the morning?

You may not worry about any of this stuff now but your solution blowing up in your face should have at the very least raised some red flags. I've had to deal with as lot of caching in projects I've worked on in the past few years and everything I say here comes from experience.

### Proposed solution - On-demand caching

If you've put a little effort into organizing your code, all of your CRUD operations on the database should be in specialized helper classes which I call repositories. Your controller calls its specialized repository (StuffController - StuffRepository), receives a model and binds that model to a view, kinda like this:

```
public class StuffController : Controller
{
    private MyDbContext _db;
    private StuffRepository _repo;

    public StuffController()
    {
        _db = new MyDbContext();
        _repo = new StuffRepository(_db);
    }

    // ...

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        var model = _repo.ReadDetails(id);
        // ...
        return View(model);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        _db.Dispose();

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

What on-demand caching would do is wrap that call to the repository in such a way that if the result of that method was already in the cache and it was not stale, it would return it from the cache. Otherwise it would hit the database.

Here's a simplified (and probably nonfunctional) example of a CacheWrapper class so you can understand what it does, using HttpRuntime.Cache:

```
public static class CacheWrapper
{
    private static List<string> _keys = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> Keys
    {
        get { lock(_keys) { return _keys.ToList(); } }
    }

    public static T Fetch<T>(string key, Func<T> dlgt, bool refresh = false) where T : class
    {
        var result = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(key) as T;

        if(result != null && !refresh) return result;

        lock(HttpRuntime.Cache)
        {
            lock(_keys)
            {
                _keys.Add(key);
            }

            result = dlgt();

            HttpRuntime.Cache.Add(key, result, /* some other params */);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

And the new way to call things from the controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var model = CacheWrapper.Fetch("StuffDetails_" + id, () => _repo.ReadDetails(id));
    // ...
    return View(model);
}
```

A slightly more complex version of this is in production on a public web application as we speak and working quite well.

Comment: Hi @RaduPorumb, it is just not possible to get all the data again per request. That part of the data we are talking about is almost static: we're talking about an update per day. It is just wasting a lot of performance by deserializing all this data from no matter what kind store for **every request**.

Comment: Are you referring to my PS or to the rest of the post?

Comment: Both :) (ps. thanks for your extended answer, but I really need a solution for the problem, not for the architecture)

Comment: @DirkBoer What deserialization are you talking about? And who says you have to get it again for every request? If you don't understand any part of my post, please ask me about it. Rather than assume the wrong thing, I prefer you ask me to clarify so I can get to the root of your issue. I'd be more than happy to provide code examples, if that makes things more clear.

Comment: Ah sorry: I was putting to much focus on this part: '...anything related to EF for **more than the lifetime of one request** is asking for trouble.'. But you are talking about changing the classes themselves. In a way the detached POCO entities are not related to any DbContext. I understand your approach, but this would mean duplicating classes for all my 'cached' entities. And you would even need to replicate the logic one way or the other, because they can't inherit from eachother.

Comment: @DirkBoer Well, the whole point here is to prevent accidental attaching of cached objects to a current DbContext. You could make a custom build of EF that somehow tracks what DbContext instance objects come from and throws exceptions when they're attached to the wrong DbContext but I think that might be outside the scope of this solution. To top it off, with my solution, you can catch these errors at compile time, whereas with most other solutions you'll catch them at runtime, if that.

Comment: Hi @RaduPorumb, I would actually almost assume already that EF would throw exceptions, because when this happens Entities are being that actually already have a unique (computed Identity) Key . I.e. when EF would throw when an object being added when the 'Id' would be different then 0, this would already solve my solution without maintaining multiple classes that are essentially the same.

Comment: @DirkBoer When inserting a row in a table that has an identity column, EF ignores whatever value you try to set for the identity column. This can be disabled in the .edmx (edit as XML) but it will mean rewriting every insert you do into those tables using EF and calculating your identity column value by hand.

Comment: You would say there would be some way in the middle. Where it does autoset the Identity column when it is 0, but throws an Exception when you are trying to add an Entity that already has a valid Identity value.

Comment: Hi @RaduPorumb, sorry for the late response as I'm on holiday atm. Sincerely thanks for all the information in your answer, but as you can see at the accepted answer, there is a solution that doesn't require rigorous change in my architecture.
I've seen that before quite a lot on StackOverflow, where people judge the architecture of the questioner instead of giving an answer, while they barely know anything about the domain model or the architecture being used. Maybe a tip for next time!

Comment: Ps: one of the biggest assumptions that you made that was not correct is that this 'static' data takes several minutes to load. It doesn't. It's more about 15 seconds. But way too long for every request. Growing the data even 8 times will not be a problem in the foreseeable, because deploying on Azure takes about 20 minutes on it's own. 2 minutes for data initialization is no problem in that context.

Comment: @DirkBoer My solution would've made a lot fewer assumptions had you provided even a simplified description of your architecture, rather than being purposely vague and not revealing anything unless asked for it repeatedly. Maybe a tip for next time! As for your accepted answer, before changing my answer I also had a solution that involved monkey-patching EF. The problem with this type of solution is it always breaks as soon as something major changes, whether it be a new version of EF, different ORM layer or a change in your app's architecture. (continued)

Comment: @DirkBoer (continued) My solution also has been proven to work in production applications with changing caching needs and has survived unchanged through ORM changes, EF updates, caching layer changes and web app architecture changes. Also, I can't in good faith recommend a hack to fix another hack knowing that both hacks are likely to blow up in your face again sometime in the future.

Comment: 'purposely vague'.. your reactions almost near trolling. Apparently JotaBe had no problems understanding the question. More information about the architecture would only distract from the core of the question. If you don't know the answer, you don't know the answer. Telling me to rewrite my application doesn't change anything about that. Anyway, you took a lot of effort, so I assume your intentions are sincere. Thanks for that, and have a nice day sir!