# Entity Framework Core is trying to insert duplicated records when SaveChanges() is called

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

My Entities are:

```
public class Customer
{
   ...
   public virtual ICollection<ShoppingCartItem> ShoppingCartItems { get; set; }
   ...
}

public class ShoppingCartItem
{
   public string CustomerId { get; set; }
   public int ProductId { get; set; }
   public virtual Customer { get; set; }
   public virtual Product{ get; set; }
   ...
}
```

The add method is:

```
public async Task AddAsync(TEntity entity)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.entities.Add(entity));
}
```

The entity that I am adding is:

```
ShoppingCartItem()
{
    CustomerId = "xxxxx",
    ProductId = 1,
    Customer = null,
    Product = null 
}
```

When I call SaveChanges() the EF is trying to insert two identical records for `ShoppingCartItem`. The `ShoppingCartItem` is created and added to the context only once. Any ideas what possibly could be wrong?

EDIT:

This is how I call the AddSync method:

```
public async Task AddNewCartItem(ShoppingCartItem shopingCartItem)
    {
        await this.ShoppingCartItemRepository.AddAsync(shopingCartItem);
        await this.SmartStoreWorkData.CompleteAsync();
    }
```

Comment: EF can only do updates if you have a unique primary key.  Otherwise it has no way of knowing what is a duplicate or not.

Comment: Can we see how you call Addasync method please?

Comment: Why is the add method async? There's no point in that at all.

Comment: @SamAxe the the `ShoppingCartItem` has primary key. @DavidG either ways the EF is trying to add two records.

Comment: How do you call that AddNewCartItem?

Comment: @Kos: Well that would be good to know.  Show us where you define the primary key for it.

Comment: @SamAxe the `ShoppingCartItme` has property `int Id` decorated with attribute `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`. I can confirm that before calling `SaveChanges()` there is no such a record in the database.

Comment: @Kos: well that's relevent information that needs to be in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I did the following:

- Cloned your repo link: [SmartStoreNETCore](https://github.com/KostaVlev/SmartStoreNETCore/tree/NETCore/SmartStoreNETCore)
- Migrated to .NET Core 1.1 with the new EF tooling (preview4)
- Added the configuration as specified in **EF ModelBuilder** below
- Applied Migration and updated database

Commands:

```
dotnet ef --startup-project ../SmartStoreNetCore.Web/ migrations add ChangeShoppingCartItemKey
dotnet ef --startup-project ../SmartStoreNetCore.Web/ database update
```

- Removed the following **duplicate tag** in `_Layout.cshtml`

  `<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>`

> `site.js` contains the click event handler for the *Add To Cart* functionality

- Started the site and **everything worked as expected, no duplicate shopping cart items and the quantity is updated as expected**

[image]

### In summary

> **I can fully confirm** the following method was being **called twice** before removing the duplicate reference to `site.js`:

```
 public async Task AddNewCartItem(ShoppingCartItem shopingCartItem)
 {
     await this.ShoppingCartItemRepository.AddAsync(shopingCartItem);
     await this.SmartStoreWorkData.CompleteAsync();
 }
```

It is a mistery to me why you didn't catch this before via debugging

### EF ModelBuilder

Your configuration should look like:

```
builder.Entity<ShoppingCartItem>().HasKey(x => x.Id); // Notice this!
builder.Entity<ShoppingCartItem>().Property(x => x.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd(); // Also this!
builder.Entity<ShoppingCartItem>().HasOne(s => s.Customer).WithMany(b => b.ShoppingCartItems).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
builder.Entity<ShoppingCartItem>().HasOne(s => s.Product).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Having a value generated automatically **does not define it as the primary key**

Comment: In this case I am getting the second duplicated record inserted into the database.

Comment: Which DB engine are you using?

Comment: SQL Server Database. Just to clear that... duplicated record but with different Id.

Comment: Mmm... can only think of a bug at this point. I don't know... Are you using the latest EF Core? [Check this answer I gave the other day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41176240/ef-core-1-1-migration-the-current-csharphelper-cannot-scaffold-literals-of-typ/41178855#41178855)

Comment: The latest version is 1.1.0, but I'm not sure if this what you are experiencing is a bug in previous EF Core versions, in the current version of EF or in your code :(, so I can't even tell you an upgrade will fix it

Comment: After update to Core 1.1.0 and 5 hours of dependencies resolving drama lol, the problem is still there...

Comment: Please, see my update, the problem **is not related to EF Core itself**. I don't think I'll have the time to work on a PR for your repository, but I can send you a patch file with my updates (for .NET Core it would be helpful to you I believe)

Answer (score 3):

`DbContext` is *[not thread safe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj729737(v=vs.113).aspx)*.  By - pointlessly, as noted in the comments - performing your `.Add()` in what is quite likely a different thread, you're confusing the `DbContext`.  `Add()` is purely an in-memory operation; there is no reason to try to make it async.  Change that and I reckon it will resolve the issue.

```
public void Add(TEntity entity)
{
    this.entities.Add(entity);
}
```

If you have any other similar usages that are not shown in your question, change those to sync too.

You *can* do "proper" async with `DbContext` but it is only for the methods that actually talk to the database, not the in-memory ones, and will not usually involve `Task.<anything>`, just the provided `async` methods.

**Edit**: for completeness, the link above is for EF6, but in EF Core, `DbContext` is also [not thread-safe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification when async have to be used. But this does not solve the problem as I mentioned in the comments . I changed the Add method and the EF still tries to add second time the same record in the same `SaveChanges()` call.

Comment: @Kos - you're not perhaps adding the item to the `ShoppingCartItems` collection _and_ via `this.entities.Add(entity)` are you?  If not, would you show us the code for `CompleteAsync()` please (by editing the original question).  Also show us where your `DbContext` is created.  In general we can help you better if you show quite a bit more code that might be relevant.

Comment: I do not add the `ShoppingCartItem` to the `Customer.ShoppingCartItems` collection. The `CompleteAsync()` method looks like `await this.dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();`. I am injecting the `DbContext` in here `services.AddTransient<ISmartStoreWorkData, SmartStoreWorkData>();` which is my UnitOfWork. Seems like that double records insert happens with tables that have many-to-many relationship.

Comment: [repository link](https://github.com/KostaVlev/SmartStoreNETCore/tree/NETCore/SmartStoreNETCore)

Comment: You imply the primary key for `ShoppingCartItem` is the DB-generated ID, but in the fluent config (in your linked code) you actually set it to `{ CustomerId, ProductId }`: `builder.Entity<ShoppingCartItem>().HasKey(x => new { x.CustomerId, x.ProductId });`.  Can you confirm there is no other row in the table with that primary key?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that before calling `SaveChanges()` there is no other row with this primary key. I did set `HasKey(x => new { x.CustomerId, x.ProductId })` to prevent the actual double insertion.

Comment: Take a look at the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592504/how-can-i-see-the-entity-frameworks-pending-changes), and use it just before your call to `SaveChanges()` to see what EF thinks has changed.  That should give a better clue as to what is happening.

Comment: @Kos looking at the comments it's not clear to me whether you are using fluent configuration or data annotations and if it's the latter, did you set the `[Key]` annotation aside of the `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` annotation, **you need both**

Comment: @sellotape The pending changes where `Modified - 0 ` `Deleted - 0` `Added - 1 Entity` Seems like EF is tracking the changes correctly but still try to inserts two records...

Comment: Did you call the `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` before, just in case? I mean before doing what @sellotape recommended