# Entity Framework updating specific fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model like this:

```
public class Company 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Company { get;set; }
    public string Company_Sort { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public bool addCompanyInfo(string userId, string companyName) 
{
    var record = dbContext.Company.Where(a => a.Id.Equals(userId)).SingleOrDefault();
    record.Company = companyName;
    record.Company_Sort = companyName.ToUpper();

    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    return true;
}
```

Now this used to work I've updated records like this before and there was no problem. But now every time it hits `SaveChanges()`, I'll get a validation error saying Gender is required I even have Gender as a hidden input on my view.

I've even tried doing something like this but to no avail:

```
dbContext.Company.Attach(record);

var entry = dbContext.Entry(record);
entry.Property(a => a.Company).IsModified = true;
entry.Property(a => a.Company_Sort).IsModified = true;

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The model is based off on a table in SQL Server which Gender is a non-nullable column. Which is then mapped and configured in a config class:

```
public partial class CompanyConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Company> 
{
    public CompanyConfig() : this("dbo") {}

    public CompanyConfig(string schema) 
    {
        ToTable(schema + ".Company");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("Id").IsRequired().......
        Property(x => x.Gender).HasColumnName("Gender").IsRequired().....
    }
}
```

Razor View:

```
<div class="dialog-content container-fluid">
        <div class="form-horizontal panel-body">
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserId)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SelectedKeywordText, new {@id = "txtKeyword"})
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Address)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Designation)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FirstName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MiddleName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LastName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Prefix)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CompanyName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FullName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Gender)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.LastFirstName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Email)

            <h5><b>Select a Keyword:</b></h5><br/>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.ValidationSummary()
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedKeywordId, $"{Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.SelectedKeywordId)}:", new {@class = "col-sm-3 control-label"})
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedKeywordId, new SelectList(Model.KeyWords, "Id", "Keyword"), "Select a keyword", new {@class = "form-control", id = "ddlKeyword"})
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default dialog-navbar" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn">Send Email</button>
            <a id="btnCancelGrant" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn" href="#">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
}
</div>
```

The view uses a ViewModel which is essentially the same as the Company Model except it has a bit more fields in it.

Is there any reason why the 2 options I've tried don't work?

Comment: Show the relevant Razor code (between the form tags).

Comment: @SamAxe I've edited it.

Comment: And what does the rendered HTML look like for the Gender hidden input?

Comment: @SamAxe It's pretty much just a dropdown list where user can select an option and click submit button. On submit it will make an ajax call that i serialize the whole form and then do a $.parseJson on it and send that over as data to my controller.

Comment: @SC.Cee it looks like you are mixing two models here.  You are using `userId` to query the `Company` collection.  Does the `record` variable in your `addCompanyInfo` method contain a `Gender` field?

Comment: @AaronRoberts Yes the record variable does contain a Gender field. Also userId is pretty much the Id for the company table, the naming scheme is just a little off. But yes I've checked the variable and it's returning the correct record info just when i only want to update the 2 fields it's saying Gender is required.

Comment: I suspect your `userId` variable is not coming through and since you use `SingleOrDefault()` it's constructing a new empty record when it finds none, then when you try to save changes you get this error.  Your view has `UserId` not `userId` - could be a case sensitivity thing?

Comment: Is the form a POST or GET action?

Comment: @SamAxe the form is a post.

Comment: @stephen.vakil That shouldn't be the problem as I debugged it and I am getting the proper records back, userId is the parameter I pass in hence the different name.

Comment: So you've put a breakpoint on the line after you load `record` to see what its values are / to verify it actually loaded something?

Comment: @stephen.vakil yep, It returns back the proper values on each field and the record variable is not null.

Comment: Your view code shouldn't have anything to do with this problem if the error is really occurring on the `SaveChanges` line and the two parms are coming in.  If it is correctly loading the record and only modifying those two properties, then it must be something else in the context that is having the issue.  Try [debugging the list of pending changes in the context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592504/how-can-i-see-the-entity-frameworks-pending-changes) and see if there's some other entity mucking things up.

Comment: If Gender is a non-nullable column, then you must set a value for Gender when passing the Company back to save.

Comment: Seem to have pinpointed the problem but have no idea how to fix it. When dbContext.SaveChanges() happen. It seems to be saving a bogus record that has null gender value while the others have valid ones. So for example if I have 3 records, on my save changes it would be modifying 4 records and the [0] record is some bogus record with random values that I have no idea where it's coming from. I tried calling it on the first line and it's still saving that one bogus record.